# Group Policies Not Applied At Startup with SSD PC

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, ssd

I have a problem with some new computers containing solid state drives which will not apply group policies at startup.  All other PC's apply the GPO's no problem.

Manually running gpupdate /force successfully applies the GPO's.

I have set the following policies:
Always wait for the network at computer startup and logon: Enabled
Startup policy processing wait time: 60 seconds.

The event viewer has the following error:

```
The system calls to access specified file completed. 
...Policies\{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}\gpt.ini 
The call failed after 1141 milliseconds.
```

I can access the gpt.ini file and policies folder just fine from the client.

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy" Guid="{AEA1B4FA-97D1-45F2-A64C-4D69FFFD92C9}" /> 
  <EventID>7017</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x4000000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-04-02T21:37:13.149910400Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>3244</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation ActivityID="{DCF633C7-4000-4643-83C6-ED71691672ED}" /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="896" ThreadID="340" /> 
  <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy/Operational</Channel> 
  <Computer>...</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="OperationElaspedTimeInMilliSeconds">1141</Data> 
  <Data Name="ErrorCode">65</Data> 
  <Data Name="OperationDescription">%%4132</Data> 
  <Data Name="Parameter">...\Policies\{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}\gpt.ini</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:**

As a test if you change the Local Computer Policy>Computer Configuration>Administrative Templates>Network>Network Provider>Hardened UNC Paths to Enabled and click into the Show button enter the following Values

\*\NETLOGON and \*\SYSVOL both with the following values RequireMutualAuthentication=0, RequireIntegrity=0﻿

**Solution found here:**

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1119601-windows-10-group-policy-issue?page=

Comment: So it was nothing to do with the SSD?

Comment: Yes I think it still is because it only does it on the PC's with SSD my other PC's I have not had to make this change.  There are a couple of tablets with SSD which do the same.  I cant explain it, I only know what fixed it.